# how to save attributes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

since i m new to rails .. i have a very simple question.. here i m trying to save a new object with properties like

```
      @receiver = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
      @sender = User.find_by_email(current_user.email)

      logger.info "@receiver.inspect"+@receiver.inspect
      logger.info "@sender.inspect"+@sender.inspect

      @newConnection = Connection.new
      @newConnection.user1 = @receiver.id
      @newConnection.user2 = @sender.id


      if @newConnection.save
       flash[:message] = "Saved Succesfully!"
```

but what it does is just saved default fields and not receiver and sender id as in logs

```
      INSERT INTO `connections` (`created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2015-06-30 20:14:30', '2015-06-30 20:14:30')
```

my connection model is like

```
       class Connection < ActiveRecord::Base
              attr_accessor :user1,:user2
              belongs_to :user1, :class_name => "User"
              belongs_to :user2, :class_name => "User"
       end
```

model migration

```
         class CreateConnections < ActiveRecord::Migration
         def change
create_table :connections do |t|
  t.integer :user1_id,  :references => [:users, :id]
  t.integer :user2_id,  :references => [:users, :id]
  t.date :connectedOn
  t.string :currentStatus

  t.timestamps
        end
     end
  end
```

please help !

Comment: show your connection controller where strong params are defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign user object but **not it's id** like this:

```
@newConnection.user1 = @receiver
@newConnection.user2 = @sender
```

And the most important is to **remove the attr_accessor** from your Connection model so it will be like this:

```
class Connection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user1, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :user2, :class_name => "User"
end
```

I would also name user1 and user2 as a sender and receiver or other more meaningful names.